# How to get weights in tf.layers.dense?

Tags: tensorflow

I wanna draw the weights of tf.layers.dense in tensorboard histogram, but it not show in the parameter, how could I do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 33):

The weights are added as a variable named `kernel`, so you could use

```
x = tf.dense(...)
weights = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(
  os.path.split(x.name)[0] + '/kernel:0')
```

You can obviously replace `tf.get_default_graph()` by any other graph you are working in.

Comment: And to get biases just use  
`bias = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(
os.path.split(x.name)[0] + '/bias:0')`

Comment: It makes a lot more sense to add kernel and bias as a property of x itself!

Answer (score 10):

The latest tensorflow layers api creates all the variables using the `tf.get_variable` call. This ensures that if you wish to use the variable again, you can just use the `tf.get_variable` function and provide the name of the variable that you wish to obtain.

In the case of a `tf.layers.dense`, the variable is created as: `layer_name/kernel`. So, you can obtain the variable by saying:

```
with tf.variable_scope("layer_name", reuse=True):
    weights = tf.get_variable("kernel") # do not specify
    # the shape here or it will confuse tensorflow into creating a new one.
```

[Edit]: The new version of Tensorflow now has both Functional and Object-Oriented interfaces to the layers api. If you need the layers only for computational purposes, then using the functional api is a good choice. The function names start with small letters for instance -> `tf.layers.dense(...)`. The Layer Objects can be created using capital first letters e.g. -> `tf.layers.Dense(...)`. Once you have a handle to this layer object, you can use all of its functionality. For obtaining the weights, just use `obj.trainable_weights` this returns a list of all the trainable variables found in that layer's scope.

Comment: obj.trainable_weights works!

Answer (score 9):

I came across this problem and just solved it. `tf.layers.dense` 's name is not necessary to be the same with the kernel's name's prefix. My tensor is "dense_2/xxx" but it's kernel is "dense_1/kernel:0". To ensure that `tf.get_variable` works, you'd better set the `name=xxx` in the `tf.layers.dense` function to make two names owning same prefix. It works as the demo below:

```
l=tf.layers.dense(input_tf_xxx,300,name='ip1')
with tf.variable_scope('ip1', reuse=True):
    w = tf.get_variable('kernel')
```

By the way, my tf version is 1.3.

Answer (score 5):

I am going crazy with tensorflow.

I run this:

`sess.run(x.kernel)`

after training, and I get the weights.

Comes from the properties described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/Dense).

I am saying that I am going crazy because it seems that there are a million slightly different ways to do something in tf, and that fragments the tutorials around.

Comment: p.s. this works for tf.layers.Dense not tf.layers.dense (note caps)

Answer (score 1):

Is there anything wrong with

```
model.get_weights()
```

After I create a model, compile it and run fit, this function returns a numpy array of the weights for me.

Answer (score 0):

In TF 2 if you're inside a @tf.function (graph mode):

`weights = optimizer.weights`

If you're in eager mode (default in TF2 except in @tf.function decorated functions):

`weights = optimizer.get_weights()`

Answer (score 0):

in TF2  weights  will output a list in length 2

weights_out[0] = kernel weight

weights_out[1] = bias weight

the second layer weight (layer[0] is the input layer with no weights) in a model in size: 50 with input size: 784

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(784,), name="digits")
x = layers.Dense(50, activation="relu", name="dense_1")(inputs)
x = layers.Dense(50, activation="relu", name="dense_2")(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax", name="predictions")(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(...)
model.fit(...)

kernel_weight = model.layers[1].weights[0]
bias_weight = model.layers[1].weights[1]
all_weight = model.layers[1].weights
print(len(all_weight))                      #  2
print(kernel_weight.shape)                  # (784,50)
print(bias_weight.shape)                    # (50,)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a loop for getting the weight of each layer in your sequential network by printing the name of the layer first which you can get from:
`model.summary()`
Then u can get the weight of each layer running this code:

```
for layer in model.layers:
    print(layer.name)
    print(layer.get_weights())
```