# how to convert Tensor objects into numpy array?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

i have built and trained a CNN, and i want to get the wieghts of the first dense layer  as numpy array . after i trained the model i loaded the model using this code

```
f = Path("model_structure.json")
model_structure = f.read_text()
model_wieghts = model_from_json(model_structure)
model_wieghts.load_weights("model_weights.h5")
```

in order to get the wieghts of the first dense layer i used :

```
wieghts_tf = model_wieghts.layers[9].output
```

wieghts_tf has this value:

```
<tf.Tensor 'dense_1/Relu:0' shape=(?, 496) dtype=float32>
```

the question is , i want to convert the type of wieghts_tf from tensor to numpy array . so i created a session and used the eval() function to do so . as shown below :

```
sess = tf.Session()
with sess.as_default() :
    vector = wieghts_tf.eval()
```

but im getting this error

```
InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'conv2d_1_input' with dtype float and shape [?,180,180,3]
```

how can i solve it ?

here is the code of the CNN model :

```
#creating nueral network 

model = Sequential()
conv1_2d = model.add(Conv2D(180, (3, 3), padding='same', input_shape=(180, 180, 3), activation="relu")) #180 is the number of filters
conv2_2d = model.add(Conv2D(180, (3, 3), activation="relu"))
max_pool1 = model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3)))
drop_1 = model.add(Dropout(0.25))
conv3_2d =model.add(Conv2D(360, (3, 3), padding='same', activation="relu"))
conv4_2d =model.add(Conv2D(360, (3, 3), activation="relu"))
max_pool2 = model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3)))
drop_2 = model.add(Dropout(0.25))
flat = model.add(Flatten())
dense_1 = model.add(Dense(496, activation="relu"))
drop_3 = model.add(Dropout(0.5))
dense_2 = dense_layer = model.add(Dense(376, activation="softmax"))
model.compile(
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer='adam',
    metrics=['accuracy']
    )
model.fit(
    train_data,
    train_label,
    batch_size=32,
    epochs=40,
    verbose = 2 ,
    validation_split=0.1,
    shuffle=True)


# Save neural network structure

model_structure = model.to_json()

f = Path("model_structure.json")

f.write_text(model_structure)

# Save neural network's trained weights

model.save_weights("model_weights.h5")
```

Comment: `layer.output` doesn't give you the weights, it gives you the output of that layer. It looks like the output of the relu activation of a convolutional layer in this case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get weights in tf.layers.dense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45372291/how-to-get-weights-in-tf-layers-dense)

Comment: Also see [here](https://github.com/google/prettytensor/issues/6) for a bit about graph collections that might help you find these weights.

Comment: @Engineero thanks for clarification . i  got the wieghts by changing  layer.output to layer.get_weights()

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
x = np.frombuffer(layer.convolution.weights.float16Value, dtype=np.float16)
```